# Delete all data rows from an Excel table (apart from the first)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Just recently I've been trying to delete all data rows in a table, apart from the first (which needs to just be cleared)

Some of the tables being actioned could already have no rows, so I was running it to problems as using `.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` on a table with no rows (just header and/or footer) causes errors.

I looked all over for a solution an could not find a whole one, so I hope my answer to this question will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: If you don't want to use exceptions for handling code flow, I would guess that you're running into errors because you have a null reference exception at some point in that call (if Table, DataBodyRange, or Rows is null you will have an error). You could fix this by error checking before making the call.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code can be narrowed down to

```
Sub DeleteTableRows(ByRef Table As ListObject)
    On Error Resume Next
    '~~> Clear Header Row `IF` it exists
    Table.DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents
    '~~> Delete all the other rows `IF `they exist
    Table.DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
    Table.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**Edit**:

On a side note, I would add proper error handling if I need to intimate the user whether the first row or the other rows were deleted or not

Comment: True, I suppose I don't specifically need to reset the error when I do. Will the `End Sub` reset the error though, or will I still need to do that?

Comment: No need for the user to know about whether or not the rows have been previously delete, it's just to ensure any old data is cleared.

Answer (score 40):

This is how I clear the data:

```
Sub Macro3()
    With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Most of the answers here assume your table is on the current sheet or you know the sheet name.   To clear a named table without referencing the sheet, I changed your `With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")` line to this `With Range("Table1").ListObject`

Comment: Perhaps Application.Range would be more thorough yet at proper choice if I understand it right?

Answer (score 11):

I have 3 routines which work just fine, just select a cell in a table and run one of the subroutines

```
Sub ClearTable()
If Not ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing Then
    ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

and Shrink Table to remove the databody range except from the headers and the first data row

```
Sub ShrinkTable()
If Not ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing Then
    ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete
End If
End Sub
```

and Delete Table to completely delete the table from the sheet

```
Sub DeleteTable()
If Not ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing Then
    ActiveCell.ListObject.Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well done for distinguishing clear, shrink, and delete.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to keep the formulas in place, which the above code did not do.

Here's what I've been doing, note that this leaves one empty row in the table.

```
Sub DeleteTableRows(ByRef Table As ListObject, KeepFormulas as boolean)

On Error Resume Next

if not KeepFormulas then
    Table.DataBodyRange.clearcontents
end if

Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

(PS don't ask me why!)

Answer (score 3):

I'm simply using this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
```

The first line stays in all cases (it is cleared, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you? I've tested it in Excel 2010 and it works fine.
This is working with a table called "Table1" that uses columns A through G.

```
Sub Clear_Table()
    Range("Table1").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This `VBA Sub` will delete all data rows (apart from the first, which it will just clear) -

```
Sub DeleteTableRows(ByRef Table as ListObject)

        '** Work out the current number of rows in the table
        On Error Resume Next                    ' If there are no rows, then counting them will cause an error
        Dim Rows As Integer
        Rows = Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count   ' Cound the number of rows in the table
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then                 ' Check to see if there has been an error
            Rows = 0                            ' Set rows to 0, as the table is empty
            Err.Clear                           ' Clear the error
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0                         ' Reset the error handling

        '** Empty the table *'
        With Table
            If Rows > 0 Then ' Clear the first row
                .DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents
            End If
            If Rows > 1 Then ' Delete all the other rows
                .DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
            End If
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you would have asked this question, we would have given you a similar answer :) However you don't need 2 IF conditions. You can combine them.

Comment: I agree with @SiddharthRout Also you have a typo `Err.clesr` should be `Err.Clear`

Comment: @engineersmnky - Thanks, I just spotted that in VBA!

Comment: @SiddharthRout - In this context I do need 2x `If`, as they both check different things. However, I'm looking at another answer that would avoid the need for an `If` statement all together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first clearcontents, then resize Table:

```
Sub DeleteTableRows(ByRef Table As ListObject)

     Dim R               As Range

On Error Resume Next

    Table.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    Set R = Table.Range.Rows(1).Resize(2)
    Table.Resize R

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The codes above wouldn't work in Excel 2010 
My code bellow allows you to go through number of sheets you would like then select tables and delete rows

```
Sub DeleteTableRows()
Dim table As ListObject
Dim SelectedCell As Range
Dim TableName As String
Dim ActiveTable As ListObject

'select ammount of sheets want to this to run
For i = 1 To 3
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Set SelectedCell = ActiveCell
    Selection.AutoFilter

    'Determine if ActiveCell is inside a Table
    On Error GoTo NoTableSelected
    TableName = SelectedCell.ListObject.Name
    Set ActiveTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TableName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Clear first Row
    ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents
    'Delete all the other rows `IF `they exist
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
    ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
    Selection.AutoFilter
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
Exit Sub
'Error Handling
NoTableSelected:
  MsgBox "There is no Table currently selected!", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the table name in advance, this is a short approach I'd use

```
With [TableName].ListObject
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then: .DataBodyRange.Delete
End With
```

No need for sheet reference etc.

Answer (score 0):

One more aspect of manipulating tables. If the table has a filter that is actively hiding rows, you might have better results by showing all the data prior to modifying the table. I use **ActiveCell.ListObject.ShowAllData**.

```
Sub ClearTable()
   If Not ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing Then
      On Error Resume Next
      ActiveCell.ListObject.ShowAllData
      ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.ClearContents
   End If
End Sub
```