# Delete all but header and first visible row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've been tasked with removing duplicates from a dataset, but in a specific way; I need to apply a filter with two criteria, then remove all visible rows except the first one, which I will be editted on the fly.

I'm sure the solution rests with a loop filtering each criteria and deleting the relevant rows. However, I'm not sure how to go about it. Using offset is no good; setting and offsetting a range from used & visible cells doesn't seem to work; it always offsets from row 1, not the visible rows.

The range Dive is from the sheet WS, not the "Compilation Sheet" where the autofilter and duplication removal is taking place.

```
    Sub Dupe_killer()

Dim List As Worksheet
Dim Dive As Range
Dim Hit As Range
Set List = Sheets.Add
Dim aRow As Range
Dim fRow As Range
Dim lRow As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim FilterRange As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Worksheets("Compilation Sheet").Activate

If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:bc1").AutoFilter
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compilation Sheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$11188").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(255 _
    , 0, 255), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

List.Range("A:A").Value = Worksheets("Compilation Sheet").Range("B:B").Value
List.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

Set r = List.Range("A2")
Set Dive = Range(r, r.End(xlDown))

For Each Hit In Dive
    With Worksheets("Compilation Sheet")
    .Range("A1:BC1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Hit
    .Range("A1:BC1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="*", Criteria2:="*,*", Operator:=xlAnd
    End With
    Set FilterRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(2, 0) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    FilterRange.Select
Next Hit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Check it out   [Get unique items](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-questions.html#Get Unique Items)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate (at least from the title) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663491/ where there is a very nice accessible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the range in Dive to be only the visible rows.

Google the syntax for

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i've cracked it. Found a nifty bit of code for selecting the first visible cell. I could then hide that row and delete all visible.

```
Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```