# Reset data rows from an Excel table (apart from the first) without breaking table

Tags: excel, vba

I found this VBA code From a JackMcKoy post, It works great for resetting an excel table (Excel16) but it breaks the table in that when I press TAB to add row it no longer adds a new row. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Clear_Table()
    Range("Table1").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: By reset a table do you mean delete all rows but maintain the headers?

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663491/delete-all-data-rows-from-an-excel-table-apart-from-the-first